# Strange deadlock using SqlAlchemy + MySql

Tags: mysql, database, sqlalchemy, concurrency, innodb

I use SqlAlchemy + MySql and stuck on a deadlock that I can't understand.

There are a few replicas of app using the same MySql database.

The query to database inserts new row to one table and updates existing row in another table.
These two actions happens under nested transaction(i.e. SAVEPOINT, [link](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_transaction.html#using-savepoint)).

The problem is in output of command "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G".
It shows that deadlock was detected:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK

------------------------
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 16854369231, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 3 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id *
UPDATE my_table SET value=2 WHERE my_table.id = 265068882
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 8 page no 966870 n bits 136 index PRIMARY of table my_db.my_table trx id 25056449336 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 16854369472, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 3 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id *
UPDATE my_table SET value=5 WHERE my_table.id = 265068879
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 8 page no 966870 n bits 136 index PRIMARY of table my_db.my_table trx id 25056449289 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 8 page no 966870 n bits 136 index PRIMARY of table my_db.my_table trx id 25056449289 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

my_table.id is a primary key. So every transaction updates its own row.
Meanwhile there is no any exception in the log from SqlAlchemy with this deadlock.

I don't understand the following:

1. How deadlock happens in the scenario above?
2. Why SqlAchemy doesn't throw any exception?

Any detailed explanation on this will be very appreciate. Thanks!

```
with session.begin():
  ....
  
  # session started earlier in the parent code
  session.flush()
  
  # find object from my_table by criteria
  existing_object = ...

  with session.begin_nested():
            # Unique object that will be inserted.
            # These object are stored in separate table.
            unique_object = InsertObject()
            # some init of unique_object
            # new unique object references existing_object
            unique_object.existing_object = existing_object
            existing_object.value = new_value # integer
```

Comment: Can you include the code you think is causing the deadlock?

Comment: @IanWilson Updated original post.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table` and all the queries in the transaction, _including_ any `SELECTs`.  It sounds like a missing `INDEX` or maybe a missing `FOR UPDATE`.

Comment: As your table size is very small, the page which gets an insert will have the data you need update as well.. you should plan your transaction to avoid these incidents.. I cant comment without knowing the flow of these transactions.. but you know it better :)

Comment: It looks like session.begin_nested() places some locks to be able to rollback changes made in nested transaction. So these locks are alive for some time and it leads to deadlocks. Refactored working with transactions and it looks ok now. Thanks!